# Are SharePoint class libraries backwards compatiable?

Tags: 2013, development, sharepoint-online

I have a solution that will be accessing both SharePoint Online and SharePoint On-Premise.

Both SharePoint Online and SharePoint On-Premise require the following DLL's:

- Microsoft.SharePoint.Client
- Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime

However, I believe SharePoint On-Premise requires version 14 of the dll's and SharePoint Online requires version 15 of the dll's.

Can I safely use version 15 of the DLL with SharePoint 2013 on-premise or is its use limited to SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 1):

Version 14 is for use with SharePoint 2010, Version 15 is for use against SharePoint 2013 instances (as SharePoint-Online is).

Comment: Do you have a source for this at all? Would rather verify it for myself before making business decisions upon this (also takes your reply from being a comment-only answer to a canonical one)

Comment: you could simply look into the hive-folder of your SharePoint-Installation. If it is 2013, you should have a "15" Folder as well as a "14" Folder (for running in SP2010 mode) in your SharePoint hive (program files/common files/ Microsoft shared/web Server extensions/). If you are running a SP2010 Installation, there is only the "14" Folder. You could also look into the GAC, when running SP2010, you will find assemblys in Version of 14 (at Maximum), wheres in a SP2013 envirionment, there is Version 15.

Comment: You can verify of your own, but I would not recommend the usage of a 15-dll against a sp2013 Environment. Even if some functions might work, you will never have a guarantee that the 2010 Environment and the 2013-client-dll will understand each other in all functions. If you insist on using one dll against both of them, you should use the 14-dll against both, because sp2013 has the posibility to run as sp2010 and therefore will be able to understand requests which are intended to run against a 2010 Environment.

Comment: Just to add to the confusion, the .dlls in the SharePoint Online SDK are now version 16. And, while basic functionality does work with both On-Premise and Online, there are some functions that are Online only.